# IFS Formula With Exact Digits

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-365

I am trying to create an "IFS" formula where if the number of a cell has 2 digits, then x, if 3 digits, then y, etc. The numbers are coming from another table with VLOOKUP.
So, if the VLOOKUP finds 2 digits, the result is "x", if finds 3 digits, the result is "y" and so forth.

I tried:

```
=IFS(VLOOKUP(B17,Table2,11,FALSE)=TEXT(VLOOKUP(B17,Table2,11,FALSE),"00"),"x", VLOOKUP(B17,Table2,11,FALSE)=TEXT(VLOOKUP(B17,Table2,11,FALSE),"000"), "y")
```

and also:

```
=IFS(VLOOKUP(B17,Table2,11,FALSE)=LEN(2),"x", VLOOKUP(B17,Table2,11,FALSE)=LEN(3), "y")
```

...With no results. I searched and nothing seems to solve this. I'm probably missing something, but I'm stuck.
Your help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry to say, majority of your formulas doesn't make sense (e.g. Vlookup doesn't as anything to your formula, len(3) is not testing for length, just always return 1 (the length of string "3")...) Please post some sample data with desired output so we can better understand your problem.

Answer (score 0):

*To fix the issue do the followings:*

[image]

**:Caveat:**
To solve the issue I've used IF instead of IFS, you may replace it.

- Formula in cell P3:

  ```
  =IFERROR(IF(LEN(VLOOKUP(O3,$R$3:$S$6,2,FALSE))=2,"X",IF(LEN(VLOOKUP(O3,$R$3:$S$6,2,FALSE))=3,"Y","")),"No Data")
  ```

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*

Answer (score 0):

You can use `XLOOKUP` to simplify this.

```
=XLOOKUP(LEN($A$1:$A$9),{2,3},{"x","y"},"Neither 2 nor 3 digit number")
```

[image]

Benefits of this approach:

1. Enter the formula once against the top of the list (the lookup value can take an array)
2. You can type the lookup and return arrays directly into the formula - no need for a lookup table
3. You can provide a default value for numbers without a match

Answer (score 0):

If your VLOOKUP always returns an integer value (not #NA), then instead of using IFS you can wrap your VLOOKUP with the LEN, then wrap that in a CHOOSE:

```
=CHOOSE(LEN(VLOOKUP(B17,Table2,11,FALSE)),"one digit","x","y")
```

Another option would be to add a helper column to your table2 that would be a formula that does the LEN transformation. Then your VLOOKUP would just return the Helper column value (and no need for CHOOSE).